# What is the difference between complexity classes and big o notation?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, computer-science, discrete-mathematics

What is the complexity class and big o for a given function?
Are these the same thing?
for e.g : n^2 + n

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Complexity classes and big-O notation are not the same thing. Big-O notation is just a notation to communicate the asymptotic behavior of a function; that is, O(f(n)) is the set of all functions that are upper bounded by c*f(n) for all n>N, where c and N are universal constants. So, in your example, we'd say that n^2 + n is in O(n^2), because for all n>=1, n^2 + n < 2n^2.

Complexity classes, on the other hand, are classes of *languages*, which we can think of as " decision problems (e.g., decide if some object X has a given property). The complexity classes describe how much computational power is required for an algorithm to solve a given decision problem. For example, say we want to decide if an array of n numbers is sorted in increasing order. Since we can do so by simply scanning the items one at a time and making sure there's no decrease, it takes n steps to solve the decision problem. Thus this decision problem is in the class P, which contains all languages with polynomial time algorithms. Note that this is a property of the problem, and not a given function. You can also decide if a list is sorted by enumerating all lists on n elements and checking the input matches any, but that would be really inefficient. Complexity classes are determined by the existence of a sufficient algorithm to solve a decision problem.